# Setting Teamcity version number with counter from file

Tags: teamcity, nant, version-numbering

I'm currently trying to update the version no. in TeamCity using a Nant build file, containing the version number.
If I just use

```
<property name="versionNo" value="2.16.3."/>
.
.
<echo message="##teamcity[buildNumber '${versionNo}']"></echo>
```

In the script the buildNumber is update to 2.16.3 but I would also like to have the counter on this version number.
Meaning I would like to have

```
<echo message="##teamcity[buildNumber '${versionNo}.{0}']"></echo>
```

But this doesn't work.
Does anybody know how to do this, tried many things among this solution http://binary-notes.blogspot.com/2011/05/controlling-application-version-number.html however, the ${Version} parameter is a clue for me ?

### Update

Made the implementation by using {0} as buildnumber in Teamcity and appending that build number to my own build number in the file

```
<property name="versionNo" value="2.16.3."/>
.
.
<echo message="##teamcity[buildNumber '${versionNo}.${environment::get-variable('BUILD_NUMBER')}']"></echo>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeamCity has a build number which it places into the environment while running your build script.

You can access the environment variable `BUILD_NUMBER` and append it to your actual version number. Then echo it back to TeamCity. I assume this would be available via `${sys.env.BUILD_NUMBER}`.

So perhaps:

```
<echo message="##teamcity[buildNumber '${versionNo}.${sys.env.BUILD_NUMBER}']"></echo>
```

PS. There really is no reason to change the build number in teamcity like they do in that article. You can leave it `{0}`

Comment: Cool thx, that helped. What I did was <echo message="##teamcity[buildNumber '${versionNo}.${environment::get-variable('BUILD_NUMBER')}']"></echo>

Comment: Cross reference; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831884/teamcitys-assemblyinfo-patchers-number-format

Comment: Documentation for the feature in TeamCity is [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildNumber), including how to get the current build counter value.