# Mix existing and AssemblyInfo patcher generated version info in TeamCity builds

Tags: version-control, teamcity, versioning, assemblyinfo

I've enabled a "Build Feature" called "AssemblyInfo patcher" to tweak the version of DLLs generated by my TeamCity builds. I've remixed info from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6831884/419956) and came up with this `Assembly version format` setting:

```
1.0.%build.vcs.number%.%system.build.number%
```

Now the final thing I would like to achieve is have the Major (`1`) and Minor (`0`) come from the original files, instead of hard coding them into TeamCity.

How can I do that?

I've guessed / tried:

```
{1}.{0}.%build.vcs.number%.%system.build.number%
```

But this gives an error. I've tried:

```
%build.vcs.number%.%system.build.number%
```

But this generates the `vcs.number` and `build.number` as major/minor instead of build and revision number, so e.g. `1234.21.0.0`.

I've read [the AssemblyInfo patcher documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/AssemblyInfo+Patcher) but it doesn't explain much at all.

I've skimmed the available variables (with the icon to the right of the input field) but found no relevant variables.

How can I set up the "AssemblyInfo patcher" so that:

- **Major** and **Minor** are **kept as they are in the source files**;
- **Revision** is the **VCS revision number**;
- **Build** is the **TeamCity build number**.

If it's possible at all?

Comment: FWIW: I've [cross-posted on the jetbrains forums](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/475369).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [File Content Replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer). It provides the ability to reference capturing groups of the regular expression and [change only specific parts of AssemblyVersion attribute](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer#FileContentReplacer-Changingonlythelastversionpart/buildnumberoftheAssemblyVersionattribute:).

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. I was aware of that Build Feature, but consider it to be a hack / workaround in this case, since the "AssemblyInfo patcher" seems like the *appropriate* thing to use. I was hoping / looking for a way to get the *Patcher* feature to work in the way I want it to. If I can't I may resort to your suggestion, or pehaps just live with the hard coded major/minor.

Comment: Actually File Content Replacer is a new feature that includes and extends the capabilities provided by AssemblyInfo Patcher. We do not remove AssemblyInfo Patcher because of backward compatibility.